# jquery dialog buttons different functions based on class

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a table row that when clicked opens a dialog.  The class of the table row is either "associated" or "unassociated".  I am trying to create the buttons for the dialog, but they will be different based on the class of clicked row.

```
  $('#opps tr').click(function(){
         var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
         $('#oppData').dialog({
                            width: dWidth,
                            height:dHeight,
                            modal:true,
                            buttons: {
         //if thisClass == unassociated
                     "Submit":function(){ //do stuff }

         // if thisClass == associated
                     "Do Other stuff":function(){}
                           }
    });
 });
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a little code refactoring.  At the heart of the answer is the jQuery function `hasClass` which will help you determine your buttons properties.  I'm also using the idea that every JSON object is just a property bag and building out `myButtons` using the property bag syntax.

```
$('#opps tr').click(function(){
         var myButtons= {};

         if ($(this).hasClass("associated")) {
            myButtons["Submit"] = function () { ... };
         } else {
            myButtons["Do Other stuff"] = function(){ ... };
         }

         $('#oppData').dialog({
                            width: dWidth,
                            height:dHeight,
                            modal:true,
                            buttons: myButtons
         });
 });
```